# How to extract and count URLs while sorting them?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I've got a large collection of pages collected with `wget` over a long period of time and I need to analyze the collection such that I:

```
1) extract all URLs, 
2) format them in a unified fashion,
3) count occurrences of URLs (both base domain and with full path; two separate outputs), and
4) sort output from highest occurring to lowest
```

On #2, for example, I might have URLs that are like `http%3A%2F%2Fblah.com%2Fworld%2Fnews`, `blah.com/world/news`, `www.blah.com/world/news`, `http://www.blah.com/world/news/`, or any such variation.  These will all need to be perceived by the script as the same base domain and full path.

Ultimately it should output two different lists like:

```
Based Domains Only:
424 http://youtube.com
325 http://facebook.com
200 http://digg.com
124 http://twitter.com
90  http://news.google.com

Unique URL:
254 http://facebook.com/mypage
123 http://news.google.com/Some-Big-Story
50  http://twitter.com/mrpopular
3   http://youtube.com/some-crazy-video
```

I've tried several variations on grep and have been hitting some walls.  Further I have been hitting some problems on getting various URL transformations and standardizations so that comparisons work properly and end up counting properly.

What approach would you take to solve this?

***NOTE**: *I would like to do this via the shell.  I could write this with `Ruby`, however part of this is an exercise in seeing how one might flex various "muscles" in the shell more fully with various useful commands/tools that will pull this together.*

Comment: You cannot assume that `www.example.com` and `example.com` are the same site. They often are, but it's not generalizable.

Comment: @tripleee understood, but in this case I would like it to be so considered for statistical purposes.  Of course I'm talking about `www.example.com` and not `blah.example.com`, ie, only `www` would be considered the same as the naked domain.

Answer (score 5):

Using awk

```
cat file
http://www.blah.com/world/news/
http://www.blah.com/world/news/test
http://www.google.com/test/sub
http://www.google.com/tet1
http://www.google.com/no
http://www.blah.com/world/news/
http://www.blah.com/world/news/
```

URL

```
awk '{ a[$0]++ } END {for (i in a) print a[i], i }' file | sort -nr
3 http://www.blah.com/world/news/
1 http://www.google.com/tet1
1 http://www.google.com/test/sub
1 http://www.google.com/no
1 http://www.blah.com/world/news/test
```

Domain

```
awk -F\/ '{ a[$1"//"$3]++ } END {for (i in a) print a[i], i }' file | sort -nr
4 http://www.blah.com
3 http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Okay, so this is pretty close.  The missing key here is that I have a slew of html files and actually in the first `cat file` step you have, this needs to be, rather, `extract urls from files`.  Thus it needs to be more like `find . -type f -iname '*.html' -exec grep "some regex to extract all potential urls" {} \;`.

Comment: So for example, I tried to test something like: `cat *.html | grep -o -E '\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))'` and it unfortunately truncated a lot of results.

Comment: Can ypu post an example of the html file?

Comment: Yes, was planning on doing this, but ran into some NDA issues.  I've about got it at present, but will try to sanitize an HTML file that I can ship over as soon as I get some time over the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Write a PHP script that parses those files (I like the [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) symfony component, but you can use the built in [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) and sticks the URL's into a database, then you can just query the results.

If you don't want to go with MySQL, you can use sqlite for an embedded approach

Answer (score 0):

The coreutils way using **[Jotne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18909845/1066031)** input:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      3 http://www.blah.com/world/news/
      1 http://www.blah.com/world/news/test
      1 http://www.google.com/no
      1 http://www.google.com/test/sub
      1 http://www.google.com/tet1

$ cut -d/ -f1-3 file | sort | uniq -c
      4 http://www.blah.com
      3 http://www.google.com
```